# How to get custom element by id in JointJS

Tags: jointjs

**I want to get element by id and change position of that element**

please find following code:

```
function addInNodes(x, y, text, ){
    inPortsMarkup += '<g class="port port_0'  style="pointer-events: none" id="in_0" >';
    inPortsMarkup += '<rect height="12" width="2" y="5" x="'+ x +'" class="port-wire" fill="#253137" stroke-width="1" transform="rotate(-90)" style="pointer-events: none" />';
    inPortsMarkup += '<circle port="'+ text +'" type="input" magnet="active" r="7" class="port-body" fill="#bcbcbc" stroke="#747474" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(-1,'+y+')" style="pointer-events: fill"/>';
    inPortsMarkup += '</g>';
}
```

I have tried `var myElements = graph.getElements();` but its not working for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You used:

```
getElements graph.getElements()
```

Get all the elements in the graph **(i.e. omit links).**

And should use

to get all elements, even links:

```
getCells graph.getCells()
```

Get all the element and links in the graph.